# Flex: How to tell if TextArea has blinking cursor

Tags: apache-flex, flash, textarea, cursor

Is there a way to tell if a Flex [`TextArea`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/TextArea.html) has a blinking cursor?  One indication is if the component is focused:

```
 focusManager.getFocus() == textArea
```

But it's possible to have a blinking cursor without having the focus.  I'm not sure if the converse is possible (focus without blinking cursor).

Edit: The rub here appears to be a distinction between "component-level" focus and "player-level" focus (per the [`FocusManager`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/managers/FocusManager.html) docs).  I haven't yet found any great explanation of the latter or APIs to it.

Answer (score 1):

The blinking cursor is a visual indication that you can now type text into the box and as such it must have focus.
It may be possible to hack a page to make the textArea have a blinking cursor while removing its focus but that would be wrong.  So under normal usage if the textArea has focus it will have a blinking cursor and if it has a blinking cursor it will have focus.

Comment: Seems reasonable, but if `focusEnabled` is set to false, the `TextArea` still accepts focus (focus ring, blinking cursor) while the focus manager reports a current focus of `null`.